# Python setuptools Upload failed (400): Invalid URI: u'UNKNOWN'

Tags: python, setuptools, pypi

When I try to upload a new version of my package I've got the following error:

```
$ python setup.py sdist upload
...
...
...
Submitting dist/django-super-favicon-0.6.0.tar.gz to https://pypi.python.org/pypi
Upload failed (400): Invalid URI: u'UNKNOWN'
error: Upload failed (400): Invalid URI: u'UNKNOWN'
```

The only one place where there is `UNKNOWN` in my repository is my egg info, created by the command above:

```
$ grep -r UNKNOWN
django_super_favicon.egg-info/PKG-INFO:Platform: UNKNOWN
```

My `setup.py`is pretty simple and worked with previous uploads without changes:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
import favicon


def read_file(name):
    with open(name) as fd:
        return fd.read()

setup(
    name='django-super-favicon',
    version=favicon.__version__,
    description=favicon.__doc__,
    long_description=read_file('README.rst'),
    author=favicon.__author__,
    author_email=favicon.__email__,
    install_requires=read_file('requirements.txt'),
    license='BSD',
    url=favicon.__url__,
    keywords=['django', 'web', 'favicon', 'html'],
    packages=find_packages(exclude=[]),
    include_package_data=True,
    test_suite='runtests.main',
    tests_require=read_file('requirements-tests.txt'),
    classifiers=[
        'Development Status :: 4 - Beta',
        'Environment :: Web Environment',
        'Environment :: Console',
        'Framework :: Django',
        'Intended Audience :: Developers',
        'License :: OSI Approved :: BSD License',
        'Natural Language :: English',
        'Operating System :: OS Independent',
        'Programming Language :: Python',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 2',
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3',

    ],
)
```

Does anybody has already meet this error, and have a fix ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think pypi may be having issues - I just experienced the same, and I can't seem to login into pypi with my user via the website.

Comment: NP - not entirely sure this is an issue everyone is happening, I tweeted about it as well: https://twitter.com/phobologic/status/732365571103154176

Comment: BTW, I was just able to successfully update my package, so looks like it was a temporary failure.

Comment: Yep, it was it ! I'm now able to upload.